# JSON Deserialization Errror

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-5

All..I have a simple JSON file

```
{
"code": 0,
"message": "success",
"items": [
    {
        "item_id": "1186247000000062086",
        "name": "18 Holes",
        "unit": "Each",
        "status": "active",
        "source": "user",
        "is_linked_with_zohocrm": false,
        "zcrm_product_id": "",
        "description": "",
        "rate": 25,
        "tax_id": "",
        "tax_name": "",
        "tax_percentage": 0,
        "purchase_description": "",
        "purchase_rate": 0,
        "is_combo_product": false,
        "item_type": "inventory",
        "product_type": "goods",
        "stock_on_hand": 10000000,
        "available_stock": 10000000,
        "actual_available_stock": 10000000,
        "sku": "1",
        "upc": "",
        "ean": "",
        "isbn": "",
        "part_number": "",
        "reorder_level": 0,
        "image_name": "",
        "image_type": "",
        "created_time": "2018-02-17T08:13:25-0800",
        "last_modified_time": "2018-02-17T08:13:25-0800"
    }
],
"page_context": {
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 200,
    "has_more_page": false,
    "report_name": "Items",
    "applied_filter": "Status.All",
    "custom_fields": [],
    "sort_column": "name",
    "sort_order": "A"
}
```

}

I have used the following code to place it into a dd box

```
var Products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString.ToString());
List<SelectListItem> Product_List = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach (var item in Products)
{
    Product_List.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.items.name, Value = "1" });        
}

ViewBag.Product = Product_List;

return View();
```

Seems simple, but I keep getting the following error: 
 *'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'items'*

I have used this in the exact same way for a different JSON record with success...any thoughts?

Comment: *Products* is an objects and *items* is a property of it. `foreach (var item in Products.items) { item.name }`

Comment: You should read [ask] and take the [tour].  Even though your posts have a score of zero or less, people have posted answers to them.  But none of those answers has been accepted, which "marks" the post as resolved here.  Accepting answers (and later up voting) helps other users find good posts.  it is a way you can help others even if you are not able to post answers.

Comment: *dynamic* or concrete model. this site may help you to visualize your json. http://json2csharp.com/

Comment: 2 things..  1. I appreciate the feedback about my posts and will try to follow through.  2. Thank you for the guidance. Very easy solution that I should have found!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to navigate to a property **items** that isn't a member of your json. Try to replace **Text = item.items.name** with this **Text = item.name** when adding the item to the select list.